# Reactjs: avoird rerender component for every update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This is my code:

```
<SymbolOverview colorTheme="light"
    autosize
    symbols={[["COINBASE:" + symbol1 + "USD"]]}
    wickDownColor="#F45B7E" />

<SymbolOverview colorTheme="light"
    autosize
    symbols={[["COINBASE:" + symbol2 + "USD"]]}
    wickDownColor="#F45B7E" />
```

If I set `setSymbole1("BTC")`, my component for `symbol2` changed too.

I want only re render component for `symbol1`.

By googling I found useMemo and useCallback, but I cant understand these.

Comment: Could you paste your code on https://codesandbox.io?

Answer (score 0):

If you components in the same page,
When all page will be rendering which mean both of them will be rendering.

What you do it's use `debounce` to change the state "on the fly" for one component.

ref : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/